# why does vue recycle elements?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using vue, and I found a bizarre behaviour while working on one of my projects.
When I update an array in javascript the items are put inside the old html elements (I suppose) so if these old elements have some particular attributes the new items are going to get them as well.

I'll put this example code (visually it sucks but that's not the point).

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3" defer></script>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <style>
        div[time-isselected="true"] {
            background: rgb(0, 255, 0);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="day container">
        <div class="selection" v-for="day in daysList">
            <input type="radio" class="radio-day" name="radio" 
            :id="returnTheInput(day)" :value="returnTheInput(day)" @click="setSelectedDay(day)">
            <label :for="returnTheInput(day)">{{day}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour-container">
        <div v-for="hour in hoursList" class="hour" :id="returnTheInput(hour)" @click="setSelectedHour(hour)">
            {{hour}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here's the script:

```
let daysList = ["mon 15","tue 16"];
let hoursList = [];
let selectedDay = undefined;

const valuesForTest = {
    [daysList[0]]: ["10:00", "11:00"],
    [daysList[1]]: ["15:00", "16:00"]
}

const { createApp } = Vue;

const vm = Vue.createApp({
    data(){
        return {
            daysList: daysList,
            hoursList: hoursList
        };
    },
    methods: {
        returnTheInput(input){
            return input;
        },
        setSelectedDay(day){
            selectedDay = day;
            vm.hoursList.splice(0, hoursList.length); //Vue is reactive to splice
            for(let i = 0; i < valuesForTest[selectedDay].length; i++){
                vm.hoursList.push(valuesForTest[selectedDay][i]);
            }
        },
        setSelectedHour(hour){
            document.getElementById(hour).setAttribute("time-isselected", "true");
        }
    }
}).mount("body");
```

To see my point:

1. select a day
2. select an hour (click on it)
3. select the other day

By doing this the hour will still be selected, even though it will be from the new ones.
That's not what I had expected nor what I'd want. I thought the new items would be assigned to completely new html elements.

How do I avoid this? I could change the internal logic of my script, but I was wondering if there was another way. Ideally I'd want Vue to create new html elements for the new items (since I guess it's *recycling the old ones*).

Comment: The default behaviour of Vue, React, etc. is to only replace the state that was changed, and keep the rest of the DOM as it was. If you don't want this, you have to add a unique `key` to your `v-for`, this ensures that each element is unique. See https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#maintaining-state-with-key

Comment: A correct way is to reuse existing DOM elements and write the logic based on that. This is what makes frameworks efficient in comparison with naive approach. "setAttribute("time-isselected", "true")" - this will hurt. Stick to `:class` bindings instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 solutions for this.
The first is to assign an unique key to each child with the [:key](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes.html#key) attribute:

```js
let daysList = ["mon 15","tue 16"];
let hoursList = [];
let selectedDay = undefined;

const valuesForTest = {
    [daysList[0]]: ["10:00", "11:00"],
    [daysList[1]]: ["15:00", "16:00"]
}

const { createApp } = Vue;

const vm = Vue.createApp({
    data(){
        return {
            daysList: daysList,
            hoursList: hoursList
        };
    },
    methods: {
        returnTheInput(input){
            return input;
        },
        setSelectedDay(day){
            selectedDay = day;
            vm.hoursList.splice(0, hoursList.length); //Vue is reactive to splice
            for(let i = 0; i < valuesForTest[selectedDay].length; i++){
                vm.hoursList.push(valuesForTest[selectedDay][i]);
            }
        },
        setSelectedHour(hour){
            document.getElementById(hour).setAttribute("time-isselected", "true");
        }
    }
}).mount("body");
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.37/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <style>
        div[time-isselected="true"] {
            background: rgb(0, 255, 0);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="day container">
        <div class="selection" v-for="day in daysList">
            <input type="radio" class="radio-day" name="radio" 
            :id="returnTheInput(day)" :value="returnTheInput(day)" @click="setSelectedDay(day)">
            <label :for="returnTheInput(day)">{{day}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour-container">
        <div v-for="hour in hoursList" :key="hour" class="hour" :id="returnTheInput(hour)" @click="setSelectedHour(hour)">
            {{hour}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The second is to reset child elements then re-render them asynchronously with the [nextTick](https://vuejs.org/api/component-instance.html#nexttick) utility:

```js
let daysList = ["mon 15","tue 16"];
let hoursList = [];
let selectedDay = undefined;

const valuesForTest = {
    [daysList[0]]: ["10:00", "11:00"],
    [daysList[1]]: ["15:00", "16:00"]
}

const { createApp } = Vue;

const vm = Vue.createApp({
    data(){
        return {
            daysList: daysList,
            hoursList: hoursList
        };
    },
    methods: {
        returnTheInput(input){
            return input;
        },
        setSelectedDay(day){
            vm.hoursList = [];
            selectedDay = day;
            Vue.nextTick(() => {
              vm.hoursList.splice(0, hoursList.length); //Vue is reactive to splice
              for(let i = 0; i < valuesForTest[selectedDay].length; i++){
                  vm.hoursList.push(valuesForTest[selectedDay][i]);
              }
            });
        },
        setSelectedHour(hour){
            document.getElementById(hour).setAttribute("time-isselected", "true");
        }
    }
}).mount("body");
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.37/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <style>
        div[time-isselected="true"] {
            background: rgb(0, 255, 0);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="day container">
        <div class="selection" v-for="day in daysList">
            <input type="radio" class="radio-day" name="radio" 
            :id="returnTheInput(day)" :value="returnTheInput(day)" @click="setSelectedDay(day)">
            <label :for="returnTheInput(day)">{{day}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour-container">
        <div v-for="hour in hoursList" class="hour" :id="returnTheInput(hour)" @click="setSelectedHour(hour)">
            {{hour}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```